# Scheduled Flow on Campaign Object - unable to select Campaigns for Update

Tags: visual-workflow, campaign, scheduled, scheduled-flow

I am trying to create a scheduled flow running every morning, checking for Campaigns which have an End Date in the past for which the "isActive" field is still set to true, and update them accordingly.

However when I try to specify the records in my "Update Records" action, I am unable to select the Campaign Object.
[image: screenshot of the issue]

Is this a limitation from Salesforce ? Where can I find documentation related to this limitation ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your user has "Marketing User" checkbox selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only users with the Marketing User checkbox selected on their user record can create, edit, or delete Campaign. Does your user have Marketing User checkbox checked.

Users that don't have the Marketing User checkbox selected only have access to view campaigns and advanced campaign
setup, edit the Campaign History for a single lead or contact, and run campaign reports if they have the “Read” permission for
campaigns.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much !